# Option field in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to search employee list depend on area name which is selected from dropdown list. I can retrieve names of areas from database into dropdown list from PHP HTML. But now I am confused how to pass selected option in dropdown list to SQL query in PHP. Also I want index numbers of
selected options. My code is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'Connect.php';
    $query = "SELECT varAreaName FROM tbArea" ;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo'<select name="somename">';
    echo'<option value="ANY">--ANY--</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['varAreaName'].'">' . $row['varAreaName'] . '</option>';   
    }
    echo '</select>';                
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, you would have to add a form tag and post the form to another php script.

Your selected option will be available in either `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the method used to send the form.

Example:

```
<body>
  <form action="your_second_php_script.php" method="post">
  // your code
  </form>
</body>
```

And in `your_second_php_script.php`:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

If you need the results to be available in the original page, you can use ajax to get that working, but I would start with the basics.

Comment: I want my output on the same form itself. I am trying but I did not get any solution for that in php.

Comment: @Anup No, you would need a combination of javascript and php for that. Just look around for ajax.